# See all the items created by the logged in user

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

novice here trying to get an ebay style e-commerce project finished!

When a user checks their profile, I want it to list all the items they have for sale. The owner in the Item model stores the username, so, essentially, I want to check the owner field of all items, then pull the ones that are == username.

Here's the code I got so far:

**views.py**

```
def user_profile(request):
    """The users profile page"""
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    user_items = Item.objects.filter(owner__icontains=request.GET[user])
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {"profile": user, "items": user_items})
```

I'm then using {% for item in user_items %} in the html.

Apologies if this is an easy one, but I'm struggling to get this right.

Comment: the logged in user is `request.user` (you **should** check that `request.user` is logged in and not anonymous!). You don't need to fetch it again from the db using the email, that's redundant (and inefficient). `Item.objects.filter(owner=request.user.username)` should give you the items. But why don't you use a `ForeignKey` instead of storing the username?

Answer (score 0):

```
# request.user.username is your logged in user, so you have to filter your owner field with request.user.username

def user_profile(request):
    """The users profile page"""
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    user_items = Item.objects.filter(owner__icontains=request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {"profile": user, "items": user_items})



# In your template, you have to use:-


{% for item in items %}
    {{item.field_name}}
{% endfor %}
```